# Can't delay function using C# .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, delay

I'm building a program using C# .NET 4.0 to visualize searching algorithms (BFS DFS etc).
The problem that I encounter is that I want the visualizer to work slower than as it is.
This is the code for the DFS part:

```
private void runDFS(DirectedGraph i_Graph, UpgradedPictureBox[,] i_PictureBoxes)
        {
            Color defaultColor = i_PictureBoxes[0, 0].m_DefaultBackColor;
            foreach(AdjacencyList list in
                    i_Graph.m_GraphAdjacencyLists) // Reset all colors to white. Not sure this is necessary.
            {
                foreach(AdjacencyNode node in list.m_AdjacencyNodes)
                {
                    if(i_PictureBoxes[node.m_StartVertex, node.m_EndVertex].BackColor == defaultColor)
                    {
                        i_PictureBoxes[node.m_StartVertex, node.m_EndVertex].BackColor = Color.White;
                    }
                }
            }

            AdjacencyList startingPointList = i_Graph.m_GraphAdjacencyLists[m_StartingPoint.X, m_StartingPoint.Y];
            newVisit(i_Graph, startingPointList, i_PictureBoxes);
        }

        private void newVisit(DirectedGraph i_Graph, AdjacencyList i_List, UpgradedPictureBox[,] i_PictureBoxes)
        {
            paintPictureBox(i_PictureBoxes, i_List.m_BoardX, i_List.m_BoardY, Color.Gray);
            Color endColor = i_PictureBoxes[0, 0].m_EndColor;
            for(int i = 0; i < i_List.m_AdjacencyNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                int neighborStartVertex = i_List.m_AdjacencyNodes[i].m_StartVertex;
                int neighborEndVertex = i_List.m_AdjacencyNodes[i].m_EndVertex;
                if(i_PictureBoxes[neighborStartVertex, neighborEndVertex].BackColor == Color.White && !m_ToEnd)
                {
                    i_PictureBoxes[neighborStartVertex, neighborEndVertex].m_WhoCalledMe = i_PictureBoxes[i_List.m_BoardX, i_List.m_BoardY];
                    AdjacencyList listToVisit = i_Graph.m_GraphAdjacencyLists[neighborStartVertex, neighborEndVertex];
                    newVisit(i_Graph, listToVisit, i_PictureBoxes);
                }
                else if(i_PictureBoxes[neighborStartVertex, neighborEndVertex].BackColor == endColor && !m_ToEnd)
                {
                    i_PictureBoxes[neighborStartVertex, neighborEndVertex].m_WhoCalledMe = i_PictureBoxes[i_List.m_BoardX, i_List.m_BoardY];
                    showShortestPath(i_PictureBoxes, neighborStartVertex, neighborEndVertex);
                }
            }

            if(!m_ToEnd)
            {
                paintPictureBox(i_PictureBoxes, i_List.m_BoardX, i_List.m_BoardY, Color.Black);
            }
        }
```

What I want to happen is that after I paint the pictureboxes - the program would hold for 200-300 ms so that I can see the change happening.
What happens now, is after I press the "RUN FINDER" button, I just see the output of the program, real real quick.
I tried using `this.Refresh()` but the paint part is SUPER SLOW and I can't even change the time it takes.
I tried using `await TaskEx.Delay(300)` but it managed to change my output to a wrong one.
I tried using `Sleep(300)` but it doesn't work on WPF.

I'm looking for this solution more than a week, but can't find it out. Can someone please help me?
This is how the program looks before running the algorithm:
[image]

The pink pictureboxes are walls.

After I press the run finder button:
[image]

I would really appreciate anyone who can help me solve this delay problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it might work to get a hold of the `Application.Current.Dispatcher`, and dispatch the Sleep call through it to block the UI thread for a few milliseconds.

Comment: Add a wait after each write to a box.  You only have to wait when you write to a box.  If you want to see the speed that the program is running then you need to wait when you write to a box and don't write to a box.